# Is it possible to extend the scope of a variable beyond the if statement without using pointers?

Tags: c++, if-statement, scope, stack

I've got a simple `Trace` class that logs entering and exiting a method:

```
#include <iostream>

class Trace
{
public:
    Trace()   {std::cout << "Enter" << std::endl;}

    ~Trace()
    {
        std::cout << "Exit" << std::endl;    
    }
};

void foo()
{
    Trace trace;
    std::cout << "foo..." << std::endl;    
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

output:

> Enter
>   foo...
>   Exit

Now I want to be able to enable/disable tracing. So I'll do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class Trace
{
public:
    Trace()   {std::cout << "Enter" << std::endl;}

    ~Trace()
    {
        std::cout << "Exit" << std::endl;    
    }
    static bool enabled;
};
bool Trace::enabled = false;

void foo()
{
    if(Trace::enabled)
        Trace trace;
    std::cout << "foo..." << std::endl;    
}

int main()
{
    Trace::enabled = true;
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that now the `trace` instance is scoped to the `if statement` and therefore the following output is produced:

> Enter
>   Exit
>   foo...

Is there any way to get the right output in the latter case, without using smart pointers? I want to have the least overhead possible if tracing is disabled.

**P.S.** Please note that my real-world `Trace` class consists of a few more lines, not just "Enter" and "Exit".

**P.S.2** Due to the performance considerations, I do not want the `trace` instance to be created on the stack if tracing is disabled.

Comment: What makes you think smart pointers will introduce overhead if tracing is disabled?!

Comment: Why the downvote? The idea isn't good, but the question itself is.

Comment: @Wolf The question is based on a false assumption and premature optimization. (I didn't downvote.)

Comment: the update smacks of premature optimisation. You probably want to make the construction less expensive if trace is disabled. Or you're going about this completely the wrong way. Smart pointers won't help as they have the same scope.

Comment: I added another suggestion for a possible Trace class and some thoughts about exceptions in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32691254/2932052). Thanks for having a look on it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes, that's the difficulty to ask the right way: too much details (about assumptions) are as bad as to few of it ;-) I tried to concentrate on the "important" (in my POV) parts.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any way to get the right output in the latter case, without using smart pointers? I want to have the least overhead possible if tracing is disabled.

Modern compilers optimize simple smart pointers out entirely. You should feel free to use RAII and smart pointers where that makes sense in your code. Code cleanly and clearly and avoid micro-optimizations like this because they almost never help and frequently make things worse.

Comment: Out of pure interest: Do you tend to find *Trace classes* useful?

Comment: @Wolf Yes, particularly for catching things that take much longer than expected.

Comment: I see, thanks. ...but isn't this what profiling is for? (Well, sometimes there is no profiler, I know...)

Comment: @Wolf You can't easily profile real-world code while it's running. But you can use instrumentation like this.

Answer (score 2):

why not put the test on enabled inside your Trace constructor and destructor?

Comment: I should've been more clear. Please see the updated question. I do not want the `Trace` class to be instantiated if tracing is disabled.

Comment: @Meysam you should consider to make the class itself cheap: to skip a scope-wide declaration depending on a runtime variable is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your `Trace` class to

```
class Trace
{
public:
    Trace()   
    {
        if(Trace::enabled)
            std::cout << "Enter" << std::endl;
    }

    ~Trace()
    {
        if(Trace::enabled)
            std::cout << "Exit" << std::endl;    
    }
    static bool enabled;
};
bool Trace::enabled = false;
```

and just create the variable without `if`:

```
void foo()
{
    Trace trace;
    std::cout << "foo..." << std::endl;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the suggestion to put the trace-enabled checking into the Trace class, as [Tom already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32691159/2932052),

> Is it possible to extend the scope of a variable beyond the if statement without using pointers?

You shouldn't try this. Even with pointers the scope limits of a variable cannot be extended. (Well, just for the record, the scope of a variable that is declared in the `if` condition includes also the `else` clause, and therefore also chained `else if`s.)

### Update: A personal thought about the trace class approach

Even I thought this kind of trace helper

```
class Trace
{
public:
    Trace(const char* scope): m_scope(scope) { 
        out("enter "); 
    }
    ~Trace() { 
        out("leave "); 
    } 
    const char* m_scope;
    static void out(const char* s) {
        if (enabled) {
            std::cout << s << m_scope << std::endl;    
        }
    }
    static bool enabled;
};  
bool Trace::enabled = false;
```

seems to be handy for tracking the control flow of a program, if some exceptions occur, you might prefer to miss the `leave` trace output. As I found out after experimenting some time with this approach, it's better to add plain trace commands.

Answer (score 1):

Objects placed on the stack, have code to place them there created at *compile time* by the compiler. So the only way to ensure that an object is not created on the stack is to do so at compile time. There is no way to achieve this at run time.

Now assuming that you do need to optimize the trace object out (you've profiled your program), one way to achieve what you are looking for is to use macros (which are evaluated by the pre-processor just before compilation) - something like:

```
  #define TRACE_ON  // comment this to disable Trace

  #ifdef TRACE_ON       
    #define TRACE() Trace trace
  #else       
    #define TRACE()   
  #endif
```

and then use it like:

```
void foo()
{
    TRACE();
    std::cout << "foo..." << std::endl;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
class Trace
{
public:
    Trace()   {
        if (enabled) {
            std::cout << "Enter" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    ~Trace() {
        if (enabled) {
                std::cout << "Exit" << std::endl;
        }  
    }
    static bool enabled;
};  
bool Trace::enabled = false;
```